# How to show Small Box Inside Content Area, which holds (text, images, links)?

Tags: custom-field

I want to generate unique TEXT+Images+Link for each (single) post, the results will be visible to content area right hand side, within a BOX. I already have a plugins WP-InfoBox (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-infobox/) it works similar ways but the developer who made, he didn't bothered the class, ID -- so it's messed-up the entire theme. I tried to change the class, ID names from the plugins but it's not working anyways. It's overlapping and I almost spend 3-4 hrs but I couldn't able to resolve it.

However, Basic things, I'm looking for

- Include images+text+link form WordPress CUSTOM area
- Visibility in the location ([see images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-infobox/screenshots/))

Can anyone help me with that issue, that would be great.

Comment: this can be done, just by returning, `the_content` with a div box

Comment: You could also go and look into custom fields for posts and use those if you needed a little more flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

From quick look at plugin's code it clearly has `wpinfobox` and `wpinfobox-title` IDs included in markup and only [refers to them explicitly in CSS](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-infobox/trunk/css/wp-infobox.css).

If you are not content with its markup you can remove plugin's filter and re-use it custom fields by your own code by analogue with [the_box() method](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-infobox/trunk/wp-infobox.php#L180).